# Why can Rey and Kylo still see each other mentally?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

After Snoke reveals in *Star Wars: The Last Jedi* that he was the one who connected him with Rey, Kylo kills him. But near the end of the film we see the two still able to see / feel each other remotely and mentally as Rey closes the hatch of the Falcon.

Did the bond remain after Snoke died or was there another cause to the link?